# Update Variable with Case Expression and use that Variable to update table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case, insert-update

I am trying to update the status of our shipping orders. It compiles but I am not returning any status when I execute the procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Shipping].[UpdateShippingStatus_ERICA]
@OrderID int = 0
AS
BEGIN

declare @ShipStatus int = 0
declare @TagsVerified varchar(10) 
declare @TagCount int
declare @Cash Varchar
declare @Payment int
declare @VehicleType varchar(10)
declare @LoadedUnits varchar
declare @LoadedWeight int
select @TagCount = count(TGTAGID) from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.TAGCUR where TGORDER = @OrderID 
select @TagsVerified = Y6PRS09, @VehicleType = Y6CAR, @LoadedUnits = Y6PRS09, @LoadedWeight = Y6WGROSS
  from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDHAD where Y6ONO = @OrderID
select @Cash = OHOCSH, @Payment = OHCASH from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDH a where OHONO = @OrderID

Select  @ShipStatus = 
    (Case
        When @ShipStatus = 3 and @Cash = 'N' and @TagsVerified like '%Y%' and @TagCount = (select a.TagsLoaded from sales.IBM.OrdersShipping a where a.OrderID = @OrderID)
            Then 4

        When @ShipStatus = 3 and @Cash = 'Y' and  @Payment > '0' and @TagsVerified like '%Y%' and @TagCount = (select a.TagsLoaded from sales.IBM.OrdersShipping a where a.OrderID = '35632')
            Then 4  

        When @ShipStatus = 2 and  @LoadedUnits > '0' and @LoadedWeight > '0' 
            Then 3 

        When @ShipStatus = 1 and @VehicleType = 'VAN' and exists(select * from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.TRINSP where Y7ONO = @OrderID)
            Then 2 

        When exists(select * from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDHAD where Y6LDDATE > '0' and Y6CAR <> 'VAN' and Y6ONO = @OrderID)
            Then 2

        When exists(select * from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDHAD where Y6LDDATE > '0' and Y6CAR = 'VAN' and Y6ONO = @OrderID)
            Then 1

    End)

FROM sales.IBM.OrdersShipping a
join [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDHAD b  on b.Y6ONO = a.OrderId
join [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDH c on c.OHONO = b.Y6ONO
join [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.TAGCUR d on d.TGORDER = c.OHONO
where OrderID = @OrderID

Update sales.ibm.ordersshipping 
set sales.ibm.ordersshipping.ShippingStatus = 
    (Case 

        When @ShipStatus = 1 Then 'READYINSP'
        When @ShipStatus = 2 Then 'READYLOAD'
        When @ShipStatus = 3 Then 'READYSCAN'
        When @ShipStatus = 4 Then 'READYSHIP'
    END)

where OrderID = @OrderID
END
GO
```

Comment: What do you mean by you're not returning any status? You don't have any `SELECT` statements that return a dataset or an `OUTPUT` parameter, so not sure what you're expecting to be "returned".

Comment: I finally figured it out... Here is the code that works.

Comment: Why do you have all those variables? You aren't using most of them. You could greatly simplify this logic. Also, DO NOT declare varchar without the size, EVER!!! There are few absolutes in sql server but this is one of them. It will use the default size. And that default size will differ between variables and parameters which drive you insane. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: As far as I can tell your first 4 cases in your case expression are all pointless (`when @ShipStatus = 3 and ...` etc), You initially declare this with a value of 0, and don't modify it, so it will always still be 0 by this point, so the cases where it is 1, 2, or 3 will never be true. I also think all 3 of your joins are redundant, but I can't be sure of this.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback :) It is really appreciated when learning. I made the changes :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I got to work. By "Return" I just meant that the table wasn't being updated with the current loading status. It is now.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Shipping].[UpdateShippingStatus_ERICA]
@OrderID int = ''
AS
BEGIN

declare @ShipStatus int
declare @TagsVerified varchar(4)
declare @TagCount int
declare @Cash Varchar(15)
declare @Payment int
declare @VehicleType varchar(5)
declare @LoadedUnits int
declare @LoadedWeight int
declare @Shipped Varchar(1)
declare @OHOSTS Varchar(1)
declare @LoadDate int
select @TagCount = count(TGTAGID) from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.TAGCUR where TGORDER = @OrderID 
select @LoadDate = Y6LDDATE, @TagsVerified = Y6PRS09, @VehicleType = Y6CAR, @LoadedUnits = Y6PRS09, @LoadedWeight = Y6WGROSS
  from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDHAD where Y6ONO = @OrderID
select @OHOSTS = OHOSTS, @Shipped = OHSHIP, @Cash = OHOCSH, @Payment = OHCASH from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDH a where OHONO = @OrderID

Select  @ShipStatus = 
    (Case
        When @Shipped = 'S' and OHOSTS = 'C' Then 7
        When @Shipped = 'S' and OHOSTS = 'O' Then 6
        When @Cash = 'N' and @TagsVerified like '%Y%' and @TagCount = (select a.TagsLoaded from sales.IBM.OrdersShipping a where a.OrderID = @OrderID)
            Then 4

        When @Cash = 'Y' and  @Payment > '0' and @TagsVerified like '%Y%' and @TagCount = (select a.TagsLoaded from sales.IBM.OrdersShipping a where a.OrderID = '35632')
            Then 4  

        When @LoadedUnits > '0' and @LoadedWeight > '0' 
            Then 3 

        When @VehicleType = 'VAN' and exists(select * from [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.TRINSP where Y7ONO = @OrderID)
            Then 2 

        When @LoadDate > '0' and @VehicleType <> 'VAN'
            Then 2

        When @LoadDate > '0' and @VehicleType = 'VAN' 
            Then 1
        Else 5

    End)

FROM sales.IBM.OrdersShipping a
join [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDHAD b  on b.Y6ONO = a.OrderId
join [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.SORDH c on c.OHONO = b.Y6ONO
join [IBM].[S10F8DCP].SALFIL.TAGCUR d on d.TGORDER = c.OHONO

Update sales.ibm.ordersshipping 
set sales.ibm.ordersshipping.ShippingStatus = 
    (Case 
        When @ShipStatus = 1 Then 'READYINSP'
        When @ShipStatus = 2 Then 'READYLOAD'
        When @ShipStatus = 3 Then 'READYSCAN'
        When @ShipStatus = 4 Then 'READYSHIP'
        When @ShipStatus = 5 Then 'NOTARRIVED'
        When @ShipStatus = 6 Then 'SHIPPED'
        When @ShipStatus = 7 Then 'COMPLETE'
    END)
where OrderID = @OrderID
END
GO
```